# What is it called in English a term that describes the self dependency of a technical device?

Tags: word-request

What is it called in English a term that describes the self dependency of a technical device, without refueling it? For example the distance a car can go without refueling or the time a battery can function without recharging it.

I need to translate into English a technical catalog and I don’t know if self dependency can be used technically (in techniques).

In my language the term is **autonomy** but all English dictionaries describe this only politically, i.e. independency, self governing, freedom etc.

On the other hand, on the internet I saw the term **drone autonomous air refueling** which means that the term can be used technically.

So can I use the term **autonomy** or **self dependency**?

> high autonomy;

or

> high self dependency.

about a product? Or there is/are better term/terms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> It is a uninterruptible power supply (like in computers to back up in case of power failure) but it is powered by a car battery and thence the time is longer

I'd call it the [battery run-time](https://www.google.com/search?q=battery%20run%20time&oq=battery%20run%20time&aqs=chrome..69i57.3221j0j8&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8):

See especially [this](http://www.apc.com/products/runtime_for_extendedruntime.cfm?upsfamily=310).

"The car battery extends the run-time."

Comment: Thanks a lot! I extracted from your sentence and put it this way: "extended run-time", or would sound better "run-time extended"? It may sound like a title or like a bulleted item among other features of the UPS.

Comment: adjective in front (extended run-time) is typical

Answer (score 2):

## 'Range' or 'Battery Life'

Your two examples, while similar, are not well-served by a single term.

The best choice for expressing a vehicle's 'runtime' would be 'range.'  This would describe the maximum distance a vehicle could travel without being refueled/recharged.  These are typically expressed as either 'under ideal conditions' or using terms like 'city' or 'highway' to describe a use case.

For a vehicle such as a drone, DJI uses terminology like "27 minutes of airtime at 15 mph" to describe the amount of time a user might use the device without recharging/changing batteries.

The 'Battery Life' would be more appropriate for describing the length of time a non-vehicle device will function without recharging.  It could be described in units of time at a given current, i.e. Ah ratings; or something more directly relatable to non-technical folks such as 'number-of-iphone-recharges.'  Or else, it could simply describe runtime, such as a flashlight that will run at max output for 2 hours on a charge.

Answer (score 1):

The time a battery can go without needing to be recharged or thrown away is called its **battery life**.

The distance a car can go without needing refueling is its **range**.

The efficiency with which a car travels  distance using fuel is its **fuel economy**.

It's a different term for different objects. There are general terms, such as **endurance** which describes anything a human or animal does without needing to stop, but it can't be used for non-living objects.

There's also some similar meaning words, e.g. **Mileage** which describes how long a car has run since it was made and **lifespan** which defines how long a human, animal, or product will survive before dying.

*Autonomy* is the wrong word, since in your examples it defines a car that can move without a human driver.

I don't believe there's a word that is general enough to be applied to anything, but apart from cars and batteries please let me know if there's anything else that you need a word for that means 'length of time it can run without needing refueling'.

Comment: Fuel economy is _not_ a distance! You can express fuel economy either as distance divided by amount of fuel (e.g. Miles per Gallon) or as amount of fuel divided by distance (e.g. Liters per 100km). The distance a car can go without refueling is its **range**.

Comment: Thank you for all your efforts! Meanwhile I have remembered exactly what the Chinese companies define the term like: [long backup time UPS](http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?fsb=y&IndexArea=product_en&CatId=&SearchText=long+backup+time+ups), but now I'm questioning it @Brian Hitchcock?

Comment: @BrianHitchcock, as you can see sometimes is long time backup, sometimes is long backup time, so which one might be correct?

Comment: As others said, the battery backup extends the run time, not "backup time".  Perhaps you could say that the battery _"allows the system to run for {a long time / an extended period} on backup power"._

Comment: @BrianHitchcock I concur. Answer requires editing. Fuel **economy** is a ratio (miles per gallon, km/L or L/100kmm), not a **distance** (miles, km or furlongs.)